# Результат выполнения запросов

Tags: c#

В `mssql` есть таблица,имеется столбец (st) , типа `лог`.  Мне надо заполнять таблицу так: если запрос выполнено успешно то 1,если ошибка то 2 , если сервис недоступен то 3. И если ошибка, то **комментарий при ошибке** в другой столбец надо. Как сделать?

```
cn.Open();

using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select s.id, s.name_ru, s.sendType, c1.cod, s.typPeriod, c2.name_ru, s.metaAlg, m.cod, s.dt_send, s.dt_beg, s.dt_send_daytime, s.dt_period_end  FROM Shedule s  inner join ClBaseItem c1 on s.sendType=c1.id inner join ClBaseItem c2 on s.typPeriod=c2.id inner join MetaAlg m on s.metaAlg=m.id", cn))
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
      adapter.Fill(dt);
      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {


            MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();
            string dt_str = Convert.ToString(row["dt_send_daytime"]);

            string[] dt_str_tmp = dt_str.Split(':');

            switch (Convert.ToString(row["name_ru"].ToString()))
            {
                case "Час":
                    Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[2]);//мм
                    break;

                case "Неделя":
                    Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[0] + ":" + dt_str_tmp[1]);//дд:чч
                    break;

                case "День":
                    Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[1] + ":" + dt_str_tmp[2]);//чч:мм
                    break;

                case "5 минут":
                    Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[3]);//сс
                    break;

                case "10 минут":
                    Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[3]);//сс
                    break;

                case "30 минут":
                    Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[2] + ":" + dt_str_tmp[3]);//мм:сс
                    break;

            }
            myTimer.Interval = Convert.ToString(row["dt_send_daytime"]);

            myTimer.datetime = Convert.ToString(row["dt_send_daytime"]);
            myTimer.id = Convert.ToString(row["id"]);
            myTimer.alg = Convert.ToString(row["cod"]);
            myTimer.Dt_Begin = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dt_beg"]);
            myTimer.Dt_Period_End = row["dt_period_end"];
            myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
            myTimer.AutoReset = true;
            myTimer.Enabled = true;                  
      }


           }
                     cn.Close();

            }
           Console.WriteLine("Идёт запись...");
           Console.WriteLine("Нажмите ENTER чтобы выйти");
           Console.Read();
}
static void OnTimeout(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {

                var id = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).id };
                var alg = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).alg};
                var date = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).datetime };
                var st = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).st.ToString() };
                var comment = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).comment.ToString() };
                var beg = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).Dt_Begin };
                var end = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).Dt_Period_End };
                var cr = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).dt_create };
                var upd = new[] { ((MyTimer)sender).dt_update };

                string sql = string.Format("Insert Into Alg_stack" +
                   "(id,metaAlg,datetime, st, comment, dt_beg, dt_end, dt_create, dt_update) Values(@id, @alg, @date, @st, @comment, @begin, @end, @create, @update)");

                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=192.168.1.156;Initial Catalog=ihd_aktobe;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$w0rd";

                    cn.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
                    {

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alg", alg);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st", st);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", comment);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@begin", beg);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@create", cr);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@update", upd);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    cn.Close();
                }
```

Comment: Конкретизируйте в чем Ваша проблема то. Исходя из Вашего вопроса ответ будет примерно такой: insert into table <tablename> (st) values (1)

Comment: Я обновил код. Мне нужно записать в `st` (1,2,3) . А в `comment`  надо комментарий при ошибке. Теперь понятно???

Comment: Какой именно запрос?

Comment: добавление в таблицу `alg_stack`

Comment: Ты добавляешь строку в таблицу. И если не получилось, ты туда же хочешь вставить туже строку, но с комментарием?

Comment: комментарий в другую колонку надо

Comment: @MaximK копался в инете ничё не нашёл

Comment: @propro17 а почему бы не сохранять ошибки в отдельную таблицу или файл?

Comment: я обновил код. Можете помочь с проблемой???